# OR with if-then statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/user/folder
for i in *; do
if [[ $(du -h "$i" | awk '{print $1}') = 0 ]] || find . -maxdepth 0 -empty -exec echo {} NOFILES. \; ; then
 echo "REDOWNLOADING in 10 minutes"
 sleep 600
/home/user/folder/script.sh
else
echo "NO EMPTY FILES."
fi
done
```

So: IF just one of the files in the folder is empty OR the folder itself is empty, THEN it will run script.sh; ELSE it will echo a string.

But the problem is that even if the folder contains one file (whose size is >0), the code still runs script.sh: what's the problem in my code?

Thanks,
Giacomo

Comment: did you test those conditions indvidually? If they are both firing, then you have a major problem, else, you can determine which is failing, then it should be easy. Do you know about shell debugging/trace with `set -vx`. Read about that, apply to  your testing and  you should figure it out. Good luck.

Comment: The exit status of `find` is going to be zero, whether or not it finds any files. (A non-zero exit status indicates an actual error.)

Comment: Also, since the `if` statement is inside the loop, it'll either run the script or echo a string *for each file in the folder*.